# Single XSD schema for a slightly varied xml files

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I have some xml that comes in and I want to validate and it can look like this

```
<hotel>
    <reservation>
         <hotelroom>47</hotelroom>
         ...
    </reservation>
</hotel>
```

or could be

```
<hotel>
    <restaurant>
         <tablenumber>3</tablenumber>
         ...
    </restaurant>
</hotel>
```

The idea is that if it is a reservation for the hotel I want to validate against one set of data as shown: hotelroom number requested, address, etc and then if it's some xml for the restaurant then I want the tablenumber, persons name etc.

I have just been learning xsd so still a noob. I have written a schema for each of the cases but am not sure what to do as I feel I want write something in the xsd file to say IF the reservation comes up then validate against this ELSE IF restaurant comes up then validate against this.

I have read the W3 xsd tutorial but couldn't see anything.

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially would want either a `reservation` or a `restuarant`. You should use [xsd:choice](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_choice.asp) which is meant for this. Then the schema can be used to validate.

Comment: Correct answer. To expand on it just a little, the complex type for the hotel element should have a content model that is an xs:choice whose two branches are xs:element ref="reservation" and xs:element ref="restaurant".